# Renaming the workbook in the properties in excel vba the ThisWorkbook to something specific so I can reference it

Tags: excel, vba

Today I was learning about sheet codenames, and discovered that you can change the name of the workbook object in the same way. [workbook object name change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sp2Y.png)

I tried to use this as a reference in my code and it worked:

```
Dim statusWB As Workbook
Set statusWB = MultiTracker  'codename in place of thisworkbook.
TestVal = statusWB.Worksheets(NewSheetName).Range("A1").Value
```

I'm getting inconsistent results using ThisWorkbook when I have two workbooks open at the same time, so I'm thinking specifically referencing the workbooks in this way (basically like using codenames for sheets) will fix this problem. Is there any reason I would NOT want to do this?  Has anybody else tried it?

Thanks!

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` should not give inconsistent results. It is the workbook containing the code.

Comment: I agree, however, it did.  It was while populating a userform - it took the data from a named range (of the same name) in the active workbook not ThisWorkbook.  A compile time vs. execution time problem?

Comment: Probably your range reference was not fully qualified.

Comment: Would be useful to post your code if this is a reproducible problem.

Comment: Possibly, I tried to replicate it and now it's behaving perfectly.  Of course.  The gremlin has moved on.  I'll capture it if it comes back.   Conceptually though - is there any reason to not do what I suggested?  Give my workbooks individual codenames so they can be addressed directly?   Thanks!

Comment: `Is there any reason I would NOT want to do this?` The main reason why I do not do this is because unlike Dot Net, VBA doesn't automatically update names of objects in the code. Let's say you named the workbook to `MultiTracker` and then used the code like  `Dim statusWB As Workbook` and then `Set statusWB = MultiTracker` If you now go back and change the code name of the workbook, the above code will not automatcially get updated. You will have to individually go and change all instances of `MultiTracker`. So in such a case using `ThisWorkbook` is beneficial.

Comment: I do not see any good reason to do that. `ThisWorkbook` cannot be inconsistent! It always refers the workbook where the used code belongs.